# Finding limit using Markov chain.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices

Here is the question:

[image]

I set up the probability matrix as:
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\
1 & 0  & 0  & 0 \\
1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}

Then, $1$ is an eigenvalue. 
I calculated the eigenvector for $1$ as $(1,1,1,1)$. 
So is the answer $(1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4)$ ?

Comment: Instead of looking for an eigenvector of $P$, you should be looking for an eigenvector of $P^T$ (that is, a left-eigenvector of $P$).  You should calculate this eigenvector to be $(6,4,5,2)$.

Answer (score 1):

We want to find the stationary distribution of this Markov chain, that is, the unique vector $\pi$ such that $\pi P = \pi$ and $\sum_i \pi_i = 1$, where $P$ is the transition matrix. This gives us the system of equations:
\begin{align}
\pi_A & = \pi_c + \frac12\pi_d\\
\pi_B &= \frac13\pi_A+\frac12\pi_B\\
\pi_C &= \frac13\pi_A+\frac12\pi_B+\frac12\pi_D\\
\pi_A &+ \pi_B + \pi_C + \pi_D = 1.
\end{align}
Solving the above yields
$$
(\pi_A, \pi_B, \pi_C, \pi_D) = \left(\frac6{17},\frac4{17},\frac5{17},\frac2{17}\right),
$$
and so page $A$ has the highest such probability.